# VS Code open editor unsaved badge missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Until recently my VS Code would show the count of unsaved (dirty) files as a badge over the Open Editors activity bar icon, like this...

[image]

Recently that badge seems to have been replaced with a message, like this...

[image]

...but this message isn't visible when the primary sidebar is collapsed.

(The Open Editors icon has also changed for some reason.)  I've searched Settings for "badge", "activity bar", and "open editor" but haven't noticed a way to get the unsaved badge to reappear. 'Have checked existing extensions, but none seem to be in conflict.  This MacOS copy of VS Code recently has been updated to 1.85.2, maybe a cause?

How to I get the unsaved (dirty) badge to re-appear?

EDIT 1: I had chosen Show Badge but right-clicking on the Open Editors icon.  Cycling through hide/show doesn't change things. (Thanks Mark.)

EDIT 2: Just noticed the badge briefly appeared as a clock icon when closing VS Code.  But still the unsaved badge does not appear it did before.

EDIT 3: Disabling all my extensions, and relaunching VS Code did not bring back the unsaved badge.

Comment: That badge number for unsaved files - over the Explorer badge - is still there for me.  Try right-clicking the badge and see if there is a `Show Badge` option.

Comment: @Mark  Yes, right-clicking the Open Editors icon does show that control.  I had chosen Show Badge.  Cycling through hide/show doesn't change things.  (I should have mentioned this in my post, will edit now.)  What icon are you seeing (two pages or the open book)?

Comment: I see the little dot - the badge - with a number inside that represents the number of unsaved files on the Explorer icon.  You could try running the `Start Extension Bisect` command to see if any extension is interfering with the badge.

Comment: @Mark: thanks again.  Now I know about the Help: Start Extension Bisect command!  It didn't help but I posted a fix as my own answer.  'Not sure why the badge disappeared in the first place though.

Comment: You have **2** **OPEN EDITORS** text shown in the image, that means you have removed/dragged that view from it's default location and given it its own Bar

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking on the message ("1 saved" in my image) presented a "Reset Location" option.  Choosing this reset the unsaved/dirty badge to be over the Open Editors icon.  It also reset the Open Editors icon to the "two pages" icon (versus the "open book" icon).

<s>What's still a mystery is how this happened in the first place.  So far I haven't been able to reproduce.</s>

EDIT, per rioV8's comment: I had mistakenly dragged my OPEN EDITORS section from the sidebar to the activity bar, then somehow also hid Explorer from the activity bar.  Now, onto new mistakes...