# How to revert icon for "Open Editors"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I somehow changed the icon for "Open Editors" and I cannot figure out how to revert it.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: reset the view locations, you have dragged that view to the activity bar

Comment: I guess the top voted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855637/vscode-scm-tab-suddenly-disappeared will resolve this.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77902798/11107541

Comment: @TimothyG. Thanks. the "View: Reset View Locations" did the trick